# R Shiny + r2d3 package - Not rendering chart

Tags: r, d3.js, shiny, r2d3

I have been trying to render a chart using r2d3 package and RShiny. The code runs without an error but the chart doesn't get displayed. The D3 visualization works when implemented outside R. Can someone help me get this particular [chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mgold/6a32cec6380b6ce75c1e) to work?

My app.R code is as below

```
library(shiny)
library(r2d3)

ui <- fluidPage(

  d3Output("d3")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$d3 <- renderD3({
    r2d3(
      #runif(5, 0, input$bar_max),
      data=data_C,
      script = system.file("examples/mult2.js" , package = "r2d3", d3_version = c("3"))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the .js file, I replaced

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));
```

with

```
d3.tsv(r2d3.data, function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));
```

based on the example from the [r2d3 page](https://rstudio.github.io/r2d3/articles/shiny.html). The animated bar chart example, shown at the bottom of the page, works great for me. But this [chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mgold/6a32cec6380b6ce75c1e) doesn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at the console of your browser? Most likely you have errors regarding it can't fetch a URL. You might need to use `d3.tsvParse`, Or forget TSV parsing and put `r2d3.data` as argument to the callback function.

Comment: I have not checked. I’ve been away from the computer that I use the run D3. I will take a look. Thank you for the advice

Comment: I have noticed that many of the d3 examples expect the d3.js file to be local but you can add `https//:`and they work. `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>`

Comment: Where does `r2d3.data` come from? Is it actually a TSV file, or a JavaScript string object that contains TSV formatted data? Somehow I doubt that.